# Load USB Gadget Mass Storage module from C

Tags: c, linux, usb

Development platform: TI davinci processor with Linux OS

I am developing C program which receives user command over serial port and does the corresponding task. Basic task is to start and stop the video recording. And for retrieving the video to host pc from the embedded device, usb interface is used.

The partition used for storing the video file is loaded as USB gadget mass storage device using following kernel module for the user to save the video on host pc.

```
modprobe g_file_storage file=/root/usbstorage
```

But i want to load(or some otherway) this kernel module from the c function whenever user send a command to connect the embedded device to host. And disconnect whenever disconnect command is received.

As of now I'm able to load this module only from the shell.

Could any suggest any possible way of doing this from within the c-program.

Comment: The easiest way would be to call `system()` directly but see [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87152177).

Comment: But that blocks the program

Comment: How does it *block* the program?